# How can I create a GraphQL query with nested {}

Tags: unity, c#

I am using GraphQL plugin from https://github.com/Gazuntype/graphQL-client-unity. I have a long query from which I am parsing it to JSON to get individual values. It all works fine. Unfortunately the problem appears when using SetArgs() in a nested {}. For example, here is my query:

```
{
  System(ID: "1") {
    model {
      type {
        SystemModel{
          CreationModel(isModelCreated: true) {
          name
          }
         }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

And here is my Unity code:

```
public async void GetSystemID () {
        GraphApi.Query query = Graph.GetQueryByName ("System", GraphApi.Query.Type.Query);
        query.SetArgs (new { ID= "1", isModelCreated = true }); //How do I provide isModelCreated here

        UnityWebRequest request = await NestedQuery.Post (query);
        JSONNode itemsData = JSON.Parse (request.downloadHandler.text);
        var parseJSON = JSON.Parse (request.downloadHandler.text);

    }
```

So in SetArgs, I have to provide a list of arguments, for example ID: "1" and isModelCreated: true. I am able to provide the first argument, but unfortunately the nested query's argument - isModelCreated is not getting recognized as it treats it as:

```
System(ID: "1", isModelCreated: true) {}
```

Do I have to add multiple {} so that it comes in right order or is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: @Philipp I am using GraphQL plugin from https://github.com/Gazuntype/graphQL-client-unity.

Comment: Also, it looks like there's an example of assigning fields in nested objects in the documentation you linked: `createUser.SetArgs(new{objects = new{id = "idGiven", name = "nameGiven"}});`

Comment: @DMGregory sorry I shall add that now. I have tried doing it in nested way they have described it but to no luck it is successful.

Comment: Sounds like you should show us THAT code in your question too. Remember, we cannot see anything you don't show us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example in the docs, it looks like you want something like:

```
query.SetArgs (new { ID= "1", 
    model = new {
        type = new {
            SystemModel = new {
                CreationModel = new { 
                    isModelCreated = true 
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

If this didn't work for you, you should edit your question to include the exact code you used and the exact error message, unwanted output, or other problem symptoms you observed.